# Concatenated String Not Working in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

C# ... this works

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM STATEMENTS WHERE [idTrip] = '2015Q15'";
command.CommandText = sql;
```

But when I try to replace the '2015Q15' with a variable as follows, it does not work

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM STATEMENTS WHERE [idTrip] = '" + myVariable + "'";
command.CommandText = sql;
```

When I run through line by line, I can see that the str sql looks fine but it does not select any records

Comment: Do you have any rows that meet the criteria of your query? BTW, you should be using parameterized queries instead of building up a string like this and executing it. That is a classic example of sql injection.

Comment: Maybe there are no records where idTrip is that value you provide?

Comment: Use parameterized queries! Not the solution to your problem, but a **must**!

Comment: myVariable="';Drop Table Traveler;'"

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM STATEMENTS WHERE [idTrip] = @idTrip";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idTrip", myVariable);
```

Comment: is this what is meant by a parameterized query?

Comment: @TKO yes. it is a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the danger for SQL injection...

Do you have checked for leading or trailing white spaces in myVariable? Use .Trim() on myVariable to rule this out. I assume you have checked the content of myVariable to be correct otherwise?

If still no results are returned: Trace the SQL that is actually arriving at the server with the SQL Server profiler. Capture the command, execute it in SQL Server Management Studio to make sure it executes & yields the expected results.

Is your database configured to be case-sensitive? Could this be the reason? If the letter casing in your myVariable content is not exactly the same as in your table it could have this effect also.